# Rubygems on netbeans driving me crazy!

Tags: netbeans, rubygems

I cant understand why Gems fetching failed, it was always working fine, i can't figure out how to solve this, hopefully somebody can help. Its driving me Crazy.

Error:

See troubleshooting section in http://wiki.netbeans,org/RubyGems for hep.

Follows output of the gem tool: 
Error: while executing gem.....(Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError) 
bad response Forbidden 403 
(http://production.s3.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/yard-defaultreturn-1.0.0.gemspec.rz)

Answer (score 0):

uncheck *Fetch details* in gem tool setting dialogue.

It worked for me.